# Find a leap year using a while or do-while loop

Tags: java

I have an assignment to ask people to input a code and find out if it is a leap year. Whatever the outcome is it asks the person if they would like to try a new input. If the person answers yes it asks you to enter a new year. If the person says no it signs the code off by printing a goodbye.

The only requirement is using a while or do-while loop. I am stuck.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class homework7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a year: ");
        int year = scan.nextInt();
        //while (yes==1) {
        do {
             /**System.out.print("Enter a year: "); //prompting the user to enter information
             int year = scan.nextInt();*/


             if (year % 4==0) {
                 System.out.println(year + " is a leap year"); 

                 System.out.println("Would you like to check another year? Enter 1 for yes, 0 for no");
                 int yes = scan.nextInt();
                 
                

             }
             else {
                 System.out.println(year + " is not a leap year");
             }
        }
        
        while(year % 4==0); 

    }

}
```

PS. Most importantly I'm stuck on figuring how to my the loop run again because I'm able to find out whether it is a leap year or not but when asked to continue I'm not sure how to make the input run again and ask the users for a new year!

Comment: I'm sorry to hear you are stuck, but it's hard to help you if you don't tell us where you are stuck.  You need to do some digging on your own and figure out exactly what it is you need help with, and then ask about that.  If we just wrote the program for you, you wouldn't learn any new concepts, and then you would be even more stuck on your next assignment.

Comment: We were told to just use a simple (number % 4 == 0) to find whether it is a leap year or not.

Comment: Most importantly Im stuck on figuring how to my the loop run again because I'm able to find out whether it is a leap year or not but when asked to continue I'm not sure how to make the input run again and ask the users for a new year!

Comment: You ask the user a question and capture the response in variable `yes`, then **never use it** for anything. As a user, I'd get really mad at your program for ignoring my response.

Comment: As for a leap year check, the full logic to check for a leap year is something like this

`((year % 400 == 0) || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Your Logic is wrong. Try to compare and understand. 
If your while loop depends on user input (1 or 0), then why are you checking for year % 4 == 0?

Some tips:
First: visualize your code and draw a flowchart. Don't just read the problem and write the code. Think, visualize and then write

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int yes=1;
    
    while(yes == 1){
        System.out.println("Enter a year: ");
        int year = scan.nextInt();
        if (year % 4==0) {

             if( year % 100 == 0){

               // year is divisible by 400, hence the year is a leap year
               if ( year % 400 == 0)
                   System.out.println(year + " is a leap year"); 
               else
                   System.out.println(year + " is not a leap year"); 
             }
             else{
                   System.out.println(year + " is a leap year");   
             }
        else {
             System.out.println(year + " is not a leap year");
        }

         System.out.println("Would you like to check another year? Enter 1 for yes, 0 for no");
         yes = scan.nextInt(); //IF USER ENTERS ANY OTHER NUMBER OTHER THAN 0 & 1, IT WILL STILL EXIT. Leaving upto you
    } 

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I see where I went wrong, would changing the while loop to a do-while loop allow me to make a message to prompt waving the user off with something like ```System.out.println("Have a good one!");``` EDIT: I figured it out, I managed to just add a simple ```if (yes==0)``` at the end and it fixed my issue.

Comment: 1900, 2100 is not a leap year

Comment: A boolean, reading Y/y vs N/n, may be a better/more mainstream way to do this. Also, as @RajeevRanjan pointed out, a leap year isn't every 4th year, it's every 4th year except every 100 years where the year/100 isn't divisible by 4, really 97/400 years.

Comment: @RajeevRanjan fixed it. I was actually focusing on his while logic and left leap login upto him. Anyways, modified it.

Comment: @AharonK fixed it. I was actually focusing on his while logic and left leap login upto him. Anyways, modified it.

Answer (score 1):

a leap year need this condition: `year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 == 0)`.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int year = -1;

while (year != 0) {
    System.out.println("Enter a year or 0 to end: ");
    year = scan.nextInt();

    if (year != 0) {
        if (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 == 0)) {
            System.out.println(year + " is a leap year");
        } else {
            System.out.println(year + " is not a leap year");
        }
    }
}
```